# javascript - click event target exclude child

Tags: javascript, html

I trying make a menu with sub-menu. How to exclude click event on child item? In my snippet, when I click on child item. Parent was remove `.open` class.

```js
var menu = document.querySelectorAll('#menu > li')
if (menu.length) {
  for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
    if (menu[i].classList.contains('has-sub')) {
      menu[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
          event.currentTarget.classList.toggle('open')
      })
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.sub-menu { display: none }
.has-sub.open .sub-menu { display: block }
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li class="has-sub">
    <a href="#">Sub-memu</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to call [`event.stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) from within the submenus.

```js
var menu = document.querySelectorAll('#menu > li')
if (menu.length) {
  for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
    if (menu[i].classList.contains('has-sub')) {
      menu[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
          event.currentTarget.classList.toggle('open')
      })
    }
  }
}
// this is the important part
var submenus = document.querySelectorAll(".sub-menu");
for (var i = 0; i < submenus.length; i ++) {
  submenus[i].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
}
```

```css
.sub-menu { display: none }
.has-sub.open .sub-menu { display: block }
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li class="has-sub">
    <a href="#">Sub-memu</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```